# Inconsistency with include/library search path in GCC (CentOS)

Tags: c, gcc, centos, gnu, ld

Basically I have two versions of [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) library:

- One that is supplied by vendor, i.e. using package manager from standard repository, namely two packages: `gmp` and `gmp-devel`
- Second one is compiled by myself from source (it's newest version, compiled with various tweaks, etc.).

The former one is located in the "usual places" (as by POSIX), here: `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib64/`. The paths for second one are `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib`. Consider that the latter is not installed yet (i.e. only compiled by `make`).

Here is some "dummy" program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int main(void)
{
    mpz_t a, b, c;

    printf("%d.%d.%d\n", __GNU_MP_VERSION, __GNU_MP_VERSION_MINOR, __GNU_MP_VERSION_PATCHLEVEL);

#if __GNU_MP_VERSION >= 6
    mpz_inits(a, b, c, NULL);
    mpz_clears(a, b, c, NULL);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

With stock version obviously it compiles without any issues:

```
$ gcc -std=gnu99 -Wall dummy.c -lgmp
```

However if I install second version of GMP (i.e. in `/usr/local` directories by `make install`), then:

GNU preprocessor `cpp` finds `/usr/local/include` path at first (see [2.3 Search Path](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) in `cpp` manual). In other words I don't need to add `-I/usr/local/include`. Moreover it's not so easy, to "force" to use header from "usual place", as `-I/usr/include` option **is simply ignored** (one solution is to add `-nostdinc` option and define list of headers explicitely, without `/usr/local/include` path).

GNU linker `ld` **behaves completely opposite**, it doesn't search for `/usr/local/lib` during compilation (or more precisely linkage), thus I get:

```
$ gcc -std=gnu99 -Wall dummy.c -lgmp
/tmp/ccCCfPMX.o: In function `main':
dummy.c:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `__gmpz_inits'
dummy.c:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `__gmpz_clears'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I understand, that I have to add `-L/usr/local/lib`, so now `ld` is using correct path. To run this program (as it's compiled with GMP as shared library) I need to either:

1. set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` temporarily (or maybe put it into `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, etc.)
2. compile with "fixed" runtime path (rpath) by `-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib`
3. add (missing ?) entry to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`, the run `# ldconfig` to update its index.

My question is that is why there such inconsistency between preprocessor and linker/loader? Do I missing something obvious?

Comment: the preprocessor step cares nothing about libraries, however it does care about the location of header files (the '-I' parameters)  The linker cares nothing about header files, but does care about the location and name of libraries. (the '-L' and '-l' parameters)

Comment: @user3629249: Of course, however notice that both steps are invoked and thus managed by one command, which is `gcc`.